# Handling Back key while showing a dialog in android

Tags: android

in my application i prompt for password in onResume(), and Before this i have already created view in onCreate()
so it is compulsory for user to enter password But if user press the Back key password dialog get disappered and user easily use the application

when dialog is Being shown,if get key event for Back key then i can easily handle this
for that purpose i implemented onBackPressed()/onKeyDown() methods of Activity But none get event for this key when dialog is on screen 
after dialog disappered these methods get event for Back key
can anyone tell me how can i handle this case

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call `setCancelable()` on your `Dialog` or your `AlertDialog.Builder`, depending on how you are creating this dialog.

Comment: If you don't want the cancel button to disable the dialog use false for setCancelable...

Comment: Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

dialog.setcancellable(false);

it works perfect

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this :

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && progressDialog.isShowing())
   {
       // DO SOMETHING
   }

   // Call super code so we dont limit default interaction
   super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

   return true;
}
```